Exception with orderBy descending true in firestore flutter
I am getting an exception when I try to order by date with descending equals true.
    final snapshots = firebaseFirestore.collectionStream(
      path: ridesCollectionPath,
      queryBuilder: (query) => query
          .where(
            Filter.and(
              Filter("userId", isEqualTo: userId),
              Filter.or(
                Filter("date", isLessThan: DateTime.now()),
                Filter("cancelled", isEqualTo: true),
              ),
            ),
          )
          .orderBy('date', descending: true),
    );

It works if I set descending to false.
This is the exception, it doesn't say much:

I/flutter (24875): Error: #0      EventChannelExtension.receiveGuardedBroadcastStream (package:_flutterfire_internals/src/exception.dart:67:43)
I/flutter (24875): #1      MethodChannelQuery.snapshots. (package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_query.dart:183:18)
I/flutter (24875): 
I/flutter (24875):
I/flutter (24875): Error: #0      EventChannelExtension.receiveGuardedBroadcastStream (package:_flutterfire_internals/src/exception.dart:67:43)
I/flutter (24875): #1      MethodChannelQuery.snapshots. (package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_query.dart:183:18)


Did you create the correct index?

Best guess is that you need av index for that query. It might be written in the complete error message.

Nope. There is no suggestion to create the index
